# JavaScript cookies and ensuring log in before accessing webpages

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want a way to log in and store a users details (maybe in a cookie?) securely using JavaScript.

The main I want to do is go from `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:3000/welcome` which I can do using the below code `document.location.replace('./welcome');`

However, if I currently type in `http://localhost:3000/welcome` address then it will take me straight there instead of asking for auth. how can I get a login page to be thrown in front of this page if no one is logged in?
any good tutorials on this? thanks

Comment: You need a server-side login/session/authentication system. Doing this purely in Javascript is impossible.

Comment: can i not do this with firebase?

Comment: If you use that as your server-side login system, perhaps yes. The point is that if your server willingly divulges data for any HTTP request, then there is no authentication protection of any sort. *The server* needs to require authentication for any "protected" HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this server side. Other important thing to note is javascript it client side and not necessarily secure at all.